# Determining how many cubes of different sizes fit in a larger container

Tags: geometry

I am trying to make an algorithm which fits as much cubes into larger cube (container), as is possible.

Imagine that I have many cubes of five different sizes and I want to fit them into larger cubes (call them containers) with the fact that I want to use as few containers as I can.

I have found that it's the [Bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), but in my case every box is just a cube - all the three dimensions are identical.

The question I have is if is there an "easy" algorithm/way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still bin packing.
Becasue you are using cubes, you can treat the the problem as one dimensional that's all.

10 1cm cubes will fit in to 1 10 cm cube

10 1cm lines will fit onto one 10cm line.

Cubes essentally takes orientation out of the problem e.g. 2cm x 1 cm could be upright or layed flat.

Comment: The only true simplication I could see is if the numbers of cubes being packed was a cube, e.g. 1, 9, 729...

Comment: Well, you are talking about simplifying the problem to one-dimensional. Does it mean that I can simply sum the sizes of cubes and if the sum is less or equal to 120 than they fit? E.g. I have three cubes - the first is 20 cm long, the second is 60 cm long and the third is 40 cm long. The sum is 120 => they fit?

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I haven't mentioned what 120 cm is - it's size of a container (randomly choosen).

Comment: They'll fit wil a lot of room 'above' them, assuming your container is 120 cube... 120 cube would hold 6 cubed (216) 20 cubes. Look at this way one 60cm cube takes up as much space as 9 20s or 1.5 40s. If your numbers are that nice, you should be able to chop out a lot of code.